# My colab won't let me import my dataset folder in drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

Code:

```
from google.colab import drive
import zipfile
drive.mount('/content/gdrive/')
DATA_PATH = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/'
import os
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(DATA_PATH+"PetImages", "r")
zf.extractall(DATA_PATH)
```

I am 100% sure the path is correct, but it gives me a `IsADirectoryError`.
The folder is split in two mini-folders, cats and dogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/PetImages` a ZIP file or is this the folder containing the ZIP file you want to extract?

The error message says that you are not passing a ZIP **file** but a **folder**.

So probably:

```py
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(DATA_PATH + "PetImages/images.zip", "r")
zf.extractall(DATA_PATH)
```

Comment: Oh. Thanks Franz!